# Looking for a cleaner way to get a winner on a Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a function that takes a 2d array that represents a grid for a tic tac toe game. Initially it is `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]` and there is player 1 which is represented as `1` and player 2 as `-1`.

The function to check the winner should return the winner if there is actually a winner.

My attempt is this:

```js
  const checkIfWin = (b) => {
    if (b[0][0] == b[0][1] && b[0][1] == b[0][2]) return b[0][0]
    if (b[1][0] == b[1][1] && b[1][2] == b[1][1]) return b[1][0]
    if (b[2][0] == b[2][1] && b[2][1] == b[2][2]) return b[2][2]
    if (b[0][0] == b[1][0] && b[1][0] == b[2][0]) return b[2][0]
    if (b[0][1] == b[1][1] && b[1][1] == b[2][1]) return b[2][1]
    if (b[0][2] == b[1][2] && b[1][2] == b[2][2]) return b[2][2]
    if (b[0][0] == b[1][1] && b[1][1] == b[2][2]) return b[2][2]
    if (b[0][2] == b[1][1] && b[1][1] == b[2][0]) return b[2][0]
  }

checkIfWin([ [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ -1, -1, 1 ] ]) // 1
```

It works but I don't think it is really elegant or clean and I wonder if there is a better way to check a winner and return the winner?

Comment: Imagine that you had a 100x100 grid and it took 7-in-a-row to win instead of 3. Can you imagine what your code would look like then? Generalize your code for any board size and any N-in-a-row and you'll have an algorithm that can be scaled down to 3x3 tic tac toe.

Comment: yea good call out @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 0):

You could write a generic function to check how many cells in a row have the same value, given a starting cell and an offset.

- For rows the offset would be 1.
- For columns the offset would be the board size.
- For diagonals the offset would be the board size plus or minus one.

```js
const boardSize = 3;

// board state in a flat array to
// simplify jumping to the next cell
// via a given offset
const state = [
 1, 0, 0,
 1, 1, 0,
 1, 1, 0,
]

function numInARow(cellIndex, offset) {
  let value = state[cellIndex];
  let result = 1;
  while(state[cellIndex += offset] === value) {
    result++;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(numInARow(0, 1)); // first row (1)
console.log(numInARow(0, 3)); // first column (3)
console.log(numInARow(0, 4)); // diagonal from top left (2)
```

With that established you could use a loop to check each row and column.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
  if(numInARow(state, i, 1) >= boardSize) {
    // row win
  }

  if(numInARow(state, boardSize * i >= boardSize) {
    // column win
  }

  if(numInARow(state, i, boardSize + 1) >= boardSize {
    // diagonal pointing downhill to the right
  }

  if(numInARow(state, i, boardSize - 1) >= boardSize {
    // diagonal pointing uphill to the right
  }
}
```

The diagonals don't really need the loop if you're only checking from corner to corner, but it doesn't hurt anything to have them in there for a board this small.

Another thing to consider is that you only need to check around the last square played. My demo code only checks forward from the starting cell (to the right and down) but it could easily be tweaked to also check backwards. This would improve performance for massive board sizes because you wouldn't be checkin the entire board every time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use two helper functions: `checkRow(i)` and `checkColumn(i)`, which check if all values are same in a given row and column respectively.
2. For `i` in range `[0, number of rows]`, use `checkRow(i)`
3. For `i` in range `[0, number of columns]`, use `checkColumn(i)`
4. If still no winner is found, check the diagonals (for which you can use another helper function)

This is extremely simple to program, so I'll leave that up to you. But you can use this approach to break down the problem into simpler pieces.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You could rely on regular expressions and represent your board as a single string with 9 characters.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```js
class TicTacToe {
    constructor() {
        this.board = ".........";
        this.mover = "O"; // Player that made last move
        this.hasWon = false;
        this.isDraw = false;
    }
    play(i) {
        if (this.hasWon || this.board[i] !== ".") return; // Invalid move
        this.mover = "XO"["OX".indexOf(this.mover)]; // Toggle player
        this.board = this.board.slice(0, i) + this.mover + this.board.slice(i + 1);
        this.hasWon = /(\w)(\1\1(...)*$|...\1...\1|..\1..\1|.\1.\1..$)/.test(this.board);
        this.isDraw = !this.hasWon && !this.board.includes(".");
    }
}

// I/O handling

document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const cell = e.target;
    if (cell.tagName !== "TD") return;
    const move = cell.parentNode.rowIndex * 3 + cell.cellIndex
    game.play(move);
    cell.textContent = game.mover;
    const message = game.hasWon ? game.mover + " has won!" : 
                    game.isDraw ? "It's a draw" : "Click to play";
    document.querySelector("span").textContent = message;
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", newGame);

function newGame() {
    game = new TicTacToe;
    for (const td of document.querySelectorAll("td")) td.textContent = "";
    document.querySelector("span").textContent = "Click to play";
};

newGame();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td { vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; min-width: 24px; height: 24px; border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<span></span>
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<button>New game</button>
```